# Vodafone Dongle Freya

Tags: release-freya, wifi

As a Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS user on a Samsung ATIV-Ultrabook I wanted to try elementary OS Freya as a possible alternative as it already includes the necessary wireless drivers.

When using my Vodafone ZTE K3805-Z with Ubuntu I have to type *sudo* *ifconfig* *-arp* in order to have a working internet connection.
If I try this using the USB-stick-booted elementary OS Freya the WiFi menu in the upper right edge disappears until reboot - and no internet connection...

Will I be able to use it with a special "hack" or do I have to take Luna ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a real sollution right now, but you could try automatically running the command at startup.

To do this, open Switchboard (the settings app) and click on 'Applications'.
[image: switchboard]

Then, you have to click on 'Startup' and after that, on the '+' sign in the bottom left corner. Copy and paste 'sudo ifconfig -arp' (without quotes!) in the box next to the wrench.

[image]